# How to clamp a fence for a router on a narrow piece of wood

Tags: router, jig, fence, groove

I have a few dados to make with a router on MDF boards.

The boards are 28 to 40 cm (11" to ~15 3/4") wide, and lengthwise they range from 80 cm to 250 cm (~31 1/2" to ~98 7/16").

I'm looking for good ways to clamp a fence for my router.

By good way, I mean: that doesn't interfere with the router when I'm routing, and that's easy to set up regardless of the location of the dado along the length of the board.

The router is a Makita RT0700C with the three bases that come standard [image]

Here is the basic setup that shows the relative dimensions of the workbench, the piece of wood I'm working on, the desired locations of the dados, and why I can't just clamp both ends of the fence easily.

[image]

Comment: What have you tried? Can't see for example why clamping both ends (as would be fairly typical) would not work well. Perhaps you need to use wider, not taller, stock for the fence so it sits flat not upright?

Comment: The main problem is that I don't have a table that is narrow enough so that I can clamp both ends of the fence. I guess I should use another geometry for the fence so that I can clamp at two points on the same side of the table

Comment: The solution might be to assemble a simple router table /fence and push your stock through.

Comment: I'm sorry I still don't see the problem, how does a *narrow* table interfere with clamping at the ends? You can position the workpiece near one edge of your table so you can clamp both it and the fence to it (the clamp body lying 'outside' the tabletop) and then route as normal with the router travelling inside the fence, no?

Comment: @AloysiusDefenestrate, grooving is often preferably done with the workpiece down and the router on top, in part so you can see what you're doing. Also here, I think you naturally think in freedom units yes? Max length is well over 6'.... potentially the largest boards here are 8' 2" x 15 3/4".

Comment: Agree that it’s good to see what you’re doing with many operations, but I’m still not convinced that a table with outfeed and infeed support wouldn’t work well. (And yes, for better or worse, inches come naturally; millimeters I have to think about.) Would still like to see a pic from the OP of what they’ve tried…

Comment: For future reference the correct terminology would have saved much confusion here. In woodworking grooves refer to a channel cut *along the length of a board*. A channel cut across the width as here is referred to most commonly as a **dado**, hence *dado stacks* for table saws. Before dado became the established name for these they were referred to a housings or housing joints, in case you come across the term in an old book (especially a British one).

Comment: Ignore my earlier comments — they were based on a cut running the length of the board.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I presume you're routing the groves across the short direction of the long brown board.

Use an edge clamping guide such as this inexpensive one from Harbor Freight:

[image: Clamping straight edge]<sup>*No endorsement intended or implied, it's just an example. [Actual link for more details](https://www.harborfreight.com/52-in-100-in-clamp-and-cutting-edge-guide-58363.html)</sup>

This type of guide will sit flat on the piece that you're routing and has clamps that will grip the edge of the piece being worked on. The clamp pads are pretty low profile, in the range of 1/2 - 3/4", so they should be able to grip onto the edges of your stock without hitting the work surface below.

If, for some reason, the clamp pads are too thick and hit the work surface, clamp a narrower piece of wood to the work surface, clamp your work piece on top of the narrower piece, then you'll have clearance to use the clamp pads on this tool. Something like this:

```
  +----------+     Clamp
  |xxxxxxxxxx|     Clamp pads around thin work piece
  |  aaaaaa  |     Clamp pads hanging below work piece, over extra piece
=================  Work table
```

IMHO, it's easier to use the round base for something like this because it's *round*. If you accidentally twist the router against the guide, you're still the same distance from the center of the cut. If you use a base with a flat side and accidentally twist the router a bit, you've moved the bit further from the center line you're intending to cut and, therefore, ruin the piece.

I've used edge guide clamps like these (again, not this particular brand) for circular saw cuts and for router cuts for close to 30 years. They work extremely well.

Comment: Thanks. I've found an equivalent product in my market (not the US). That looks like it will solve the problem.

Comment: Please remember the [proper way of saying thanks](https://woodworking.stackexchange.com/help/why-vote).

Comment: 100% on using a round base or the rounded sides of one of the usual plunge-router bases, unless a jig that constrains the router base so it can't shift side to side is being used.

Answer (score 1):

So I was inspired by FreeMan answer, and it turns out I had half of the solution already.

I've been using parallel clamps , Bessey Revo and Uniklamp, for some time, and it can be solved easily using an off cut like this:

[image]

It works because: the jaws have a large, flat contact area, and the clamp will right itself when tightening because it is a bit slippy.

You can always put the clamp at an angle if the jaws are touching the workbench;

It's important that the off cut has the exact same width as the piece you're going to cut, and has a factory right angle / edge for optimal results.

I like this because the footprint is really minimal; you can even put the handle on the other side (at the end of the cut) to have even less things to grab against (router cable, clothes..)

Comment: FWIW: You could add a "cleat" (or whatever you want to call it) to the dark brown guide board and register the guide to a previously cut dado to ensure that the spacing between the dadoes is exact .

Comment: Makes sense.  The current iteration (#2) already has two pieces of wood on the ends so that it slides parallel to the work piece and always clamp really tight. This will be in iteration #3 maybe.. though I don't really need them in the current project (dadoes are not spaced equally as in the freecad drawing)

Answer (score 1):

I would make a basic 'T-square' jig for this from a scrap of MDF or ply<sup>1</sup>, with a long plywood or hardwood fence<sup>2</sup> glued and screwed/nailed underneath one end.

This would give automatic 90° registration each time, so no fussing about aligning a plain board each time it's moved.

Additionally:

- both the jig and the workpiece are held in place by the same strong clamp acting downwards (so the clamping force does the most good);
- it extends the bearing surface for the router which helps ensure the full length of the dado is milled equally.

Even if you're confident in your clamp's hold, e.g. if you were to use a large C-clamp, it would still be a good idea to lightly clamp elsewhere along the board.

---

<sup>1</sup> The body of the jig must have one good straight edge, but preferably the other edge should be parallel so the router can be run along either side.

<sup>2</sup> Long to give good registration; I suggest making it at least 200mm in length. If you can do it easily I would plane or joint the mating surface of the fence at a slight angle, 1° or a bit less is enough. This isn't vital, but helps ensure an especially firm hold as the clamp is tightened.

Comment: can you elaborate on the 1 degree angle ? I don't understand where it is

Comment: The mating surface — the top of the fence where it will be joined to the underside of the MDF/ply. So instead of the inside angle being 90° it's ~89°.

Answer (score 1):

Use a "guide board" that features a cleat that will fit down into a previously cut dado and you can use a clamp that is oriented perpendicular to the work piece (and bench top) to lock cleat of the guide into a previously cut dado. This will ensure that all the dadoes are equally spaced without measuring (inviting error) the space.

In this way the lateral motion is constrained by the guide board in the dado and the guide board is secured to the work piece using the same clamping force designated to hold the work piece to the bench.

Cut the initial dado by running the cleat along the edge of the work piece. Getting the first dado positioned correctly may require off-setting the cleat along the width of the guide block or other allowances, but once you have the first dado cut, move the guide board to the newly cut dado and repeat.

Comment: Excellent idea, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you've come up with a solution that works for you, which is great. However, a solution that might be simpler, and perhaps useful in the future, is to just turn the workpiece 90°, so that you can put a clamp on both sides of the fence and then route the dado parallel to the edge of the bench. Or, equivalently, move the fence to the end of the bench and clamp both sides there.

Another good solution if you're doing a lot of these is to make a custom base for the router that includes a bar set at an appropriate distance from the bit so that the bar is guided by the edge of the workpiece or one side of the previous dado, giving you evenly spaced dados with no need to unclamp, reposition, and reclamp a separate fence.

A third option is to use a larger fence. If we agree to call the side of the fence that the router bears against the *width*, then a fence that's *longer* would let you clamp in two places along the same edge of the bench, which will hold it just as securely in place as clamping along the width.

A fourth option is to drill a hole in your bench. It's very common to have holes in workbenches; they're used both for bench dogs (which give a vertical surface to clamp against with e.g. a vise), and also for clamping work to the surface using any of a variety of hold-down clamps.

Comment: I was trying to avoid doing this, because this means that I now need the work piece perpendicular to the table and I don't necessarily have the room in that direction. Also, it will be most unsupported, meaning I have to support it somehow. Lastly, the path of router is not great relative to my body, the fence and the clamps....

Comment: @alecail No more than half of the workpiece would be unsupported -- you could always position the part you're working on over the bench. Set the fence on the other side of the dado if needed. But my workbench is against a wall, so I understand the space constraint. I've added a couple other options. There are almost always several ways to solve a problem in woodworking, rarely one "right" way to do anything.

Comment: I've ordered a straight edge clamp guide, but all of the tips I gathered here and there will come handy at some point for sure